# AWS Cloud Formation not replacing insances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-auto-scaling

I have created an autoscaling group with aws cloud formation but anytime I change the userdata, the instances don't get replaced. Is there a way to force this behavior?

Comment: There really isn't a great way using CF other than making the instance part of ASG with an [upgrade policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement instance-refresh for ASG: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/asg-instance-refresh.html

OR

Manually you need to terminate the instance and new instance should automatically spin-up depending on ASG configuration. You should able to see userdata